# MySQL query and Output in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, I like find out how many users in groupid=1, and print out all those members in that group into an array,.

```
    groups table
    userid   groupid
      1         1
      2         1
      3         1
      4         2
      5         2


      users table
      userid    name
      1         tom
      2         tracy
      3         dave
      4         connie
      5         tim

   $query "SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM `groups` WHERE `grouped`=`1`";
   $result=mysql_query($query);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

   $num_users;
   $num_users=$row['COUNT(userid)'];

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

     }


     $member_list;
      $member_list={
    //key(userid)  value(name)
     '1'=>'tom',
     '2'=>'tracy',
      '3'=>'dave'
        }
```

I don't know how to get that $member_list array with the data as shown above? any ideas?

Comment: Your query says `grouped` shouldn't it be `groupid`?

Answer (score 1):

You have the code:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 }
```

This sets $row to the value one one of the rows from your query, then throws it away and replaces it with the next value. You need to save that information before moving to the next row. Try this:

```
$member_list = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $member_list[$row['userid']] = $row['name'];
}
```

After that you have all your members in `$member_list` and you can iterate over that, use print_r(), get a specific member's data, or whatever else you want.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
$sql = "select groups.id, user.id, user.name from groups INNER JOIN users ON groups.userid = users.userid where groupid = 1";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) {
           $users = array();
       while($fields = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
           $users[$fields['user_id']] = $fields['name'];
       }
    } 

print_r($users);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I haven't tested it, but I think it will work.

```
$query = "SELECT userid FROM groups WHERE groupid='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $userids[] = $row["userid"];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (in_array($row["userid"], $userids) {
        $users[$row["userid"]] = $row["name"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        printf ("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row["name"]);
    }
```

OR

```
    /*everytime it fetches the row, adds it to array...*/
    while($r[]=mysql_fetch_array($sql));

    echo "<pre>";
    //= Prints $r as array =================//
    print_r ($r);
    //=============================//
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I don't necessary need to print out but need to add to $member_list.  $member_list=array();